# Trouble passing a page from Splinter to lxml

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I'm having some trouble taking the current page in splinter and running it through lxml. I can't go directly through a request due to logging in using splinter.
**Pt1 Is Solved**

```
    browser.visit('www.site.com')  #Access
browser.fill('username', 'userName') #Login
browser.fill('password', 'sekretPass') #Login
button = browser.find_by_name('commit') #Login
button.click() #Login

divs = browser.find_by_id("child-89751")
within = divs.first.find_by_name('calculated-grade')
if browser.is_text_present('Current Class Schedule'):
    print("Success")
    print(within)
page = browser.html
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
grades = tree.xpath('//span[@class="numeric-grade"]/text()')
print ('Grades: ', grades)
```

This results in *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'* I'm feeling pretty stuck with this one.

**Pt2 Solved, I'm dumb** 
Now my second xpath produces *[]* not the full array like grades does

```
page = browser.html
tree = html.fromstring(page)
classes = tree.xpath('//span[@class="class-name"]/text()')
grades = tree.xpath('//span[@class="numeric-grade"]/text()')

print ('Classes: ', classes) #Prints empty array
print ('Grades: ', grades) #Prints full array of grades
```

Comment: try `tree = html.fromstring(page)`

Comment: @Andersson That solved it, of all the variations I tried the one I missed was the one I needed.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer.